# How to add SPF domain record for one email address only

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I have a VPS hosting with public IP and custom domain. I am sending email from the server, but the email is recognized as spam by google. I want to add and SPF domain record. I could follow the documentation, but I could restrict it a bit more.

I use only one email address **noreply@example.com**. Should I add SPF record for that only one address? Or the entire domain?

Comment: What portion of an SPF record do you propose to use for this? SPF records are domain-wide.

Comment: I am newbie in DNS. I just want to tell to SPAM checkers that only one email address is valid from this IP. So it seems my question does not make sense at all.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that with SPF, it's at the domain level.

Answer (score -1):

If you sub-domain it like noreply@subdomain.example.com then you can SPF that sub-domain and leave your main domain without an SPF.